# Can not find Civicrm.settings.php

Tags: drupal, civicrm.settings.php

Excuse me I am new to Civicrm and got stuck, I installed Civicrm-drupal from github, I wanted to check if the configurations are correct so I ran the command "civix civicrm:ping", but I got this exception:

[Exception]
  Failed to locate civicrm.settings.php. By default, this tool searches the p
  arent directories for a standard CMS (Drupal, WordPress, etal) and standard
   civicrm.settings.php. Symlinks and multisite configurations may interfere.
   To customize, set variable CIVICRM_SETTINGS to point to the preferred civi
  crm.settings.php.
civicrm:ping

I searched for this exception and found out that I need to change the directory where the civicrm.settings.php is, and usually it is in this path: sites/default/civicrm.settings.php.

Now the problem is that I can not find Civicrm.settings.php anywhere, not in the above path nor anywhere.

Please advise me.

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally you don't install from github you would get it from https://civicrm.org/download and then follow the instructions at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/drupal7

If you are looking to do *development* it might be easiest to start here instead: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/buildkit/

Comment: Do I download Civicrm from this link https://civicrm.org/download if I am working on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes. All operating systems.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much

Comment: I am sorry, a last question please, is civicrm.settings.php.template the same as civicrm.settings.php ? @Demerit

Comment: No. You need to follow the instructions at the link above in the admin guide, which will install civicrm, and it will create civicrm.settings.php. If you need step-by-step help you can go to chat.civicrm.org or consider contacting someone from https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors

Comment: Alright, thanks again